# Pass props to the first child using this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know the way we pass props to children when using `this.props.children` the following way:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child: any, index: number) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
                Visibility: this.state.visibility,
        });
});
```

To pass prop to only the first child I can use the index and wrap the `cloneElement` call in an `if (index === 0)`, but this won't stop `map` from interating over all the children.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can break the loop right after index 0 is reached. Thanks!

Comment: If you only render the first child, what about the other children?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering if there's a way I can break the loop right after index 0 is reached. Thanks!

Don't use `map` at all, then, if you only want the first child.

```
const child = (Array.isArray(this.props.children) ? this.props.children[0] : this.props.children) || null;
return child && React.cloneElement(
    child,
    {Visibility: this.state.visibility }
);
```

That first bit:

```
const child = (Array.isArray(this.props.children) ? this.props.children[0] : this.props.children) || null;
```

...guards against the fact that `this.props.children` is only an array when there are multiple children ([details](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)); otherwise, it's the single child passed, or `undefined` if no children are passed (which we convert to `null` so we can directly return it from `render`).

Then the `return child &&` guards aginst the possibility there were no children at all.

Example with all those situations:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      visibility: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    const child = (Array.isArray(this.props.children) ? this.props.children[0] : this.props.children) || null;
    return child && React.cloneElement(
        child,
        {Visibility: String(this.state.visibility) }
    );
  }
}

const Child = props => <div>Visibility: {props.Visibility}</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Example />
    <Example><Child/></Example>
    <Example><Child/><Child/></Example>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When there is only one child then `this.props.children` is an `object` instead of an `array`.  In that case `this.props.children[0]` will be undefined. It would be better to check that case in your code.

Comment: Can you explain what the `this.props.children[0] &&` is for?

Comment: @PrakashSharma - Heaven help us, really? (Goes off and verifies.) ***sigh*** What poor design. Thanks for letting me know, fixed.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty - It's a "guard" against the possibility there are no children at all.

Answer (score 4):

Since you only need the the first item, there is no need to loop through them.

`React.Children.toArray()` will always give you an array, regardless if you have one or multiple children, which saves you some of the checks in T.J's answer.

So here is a slightly shorter (and imo cleaner) solution:

```
  const child = React.Children.toArray(children)[0];
  if (child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {Visibility: this.state.visibility});
  }
  return null;
```

---

> `React.Children.toArray(children)`
>
> Returns the children opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child. Useful if you want to manipulate collections of children in your render methods, especially if you want to reorder or slice this.props.children before passing it down.